# Distribute bananas to monkeys

Tags: permutations, combinations

How many ways can we distribute 43 bananas to 11 baby monkeys and 1 mother monkey, such that every baby monkey gets at least 2 bananas and the mother monkey gets at least 1?

I start by giving each baby monkey 2 bananas which leaves 21 bananas to be divided up. But will this be 21 choose 12 or 21 Choose 11 to calculate the answer?

Comment: are all baby monkeys identical?

Comment: I am guessing not, because no two monkeys can really be identical, I guess we can pretend that we are in the jungle giving out bananas!

Comment: good to see you still rock your khakis with a cuff and a crease

Comment: To use star-and-bars here assume all bananas are identical and all monkeys are different, then the answer works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allocate the necessary $11 \cdot 2 + 1 = 23$ bananas first. Then there are $\binom{20+12-1}{12-1} = \binom{31}{11}$ ways to allocate the remaining $20$ bananas among the $12$ monkeys.

Comment: This assumes that the babies are distinct, which is not clear in the original problem

Comment: no, that doesn't work because frequently some babies get the same number of bananas.  You are into partitions, not compositions, which are much more complicated to evaluate.

Comment: This is what confuses me. When questions say students, monkeys, boxes etc, do we assume they are identical or distinct?

Comment: Ok students are not identical and neither are monkeys!